# Recovering private key from keystore file

Tags: ether, private-key, keystore, password

Recently I came across my old keystore file from the original Ethereum Wallet that I used back in 2017. Unfortunately I cannot find the private key or password for that wallet anymore, big problem of not writing it down on a piece of paper and save that...
The issue is that I am hoping to recover the private key from my keystore file with coding or another way. I have been trying to look it up but couldn't find something useful so far.
Is there anyone who knows a way to recover the private key from your keystore file without the password?

Comment: BTW, it's 'keystore', not 'keystone'.

Comment: It cannot be done without password, you can try to hack the password it could be easy if u know your password pattern (maybe mask attack or guess https://www.itpro.co.uk/security/34616/the-top-password-cracking-techniques-used-by-hackers) however it will probably take a lot of time and effort

Answer (score 4):

**Private key recovery instructions:**

1. Download and install NodeJS
2. Create a new folder, and:

   - Copy your key-store file into this folder
   - Create a new file called `run.js` in this folder
3. Open a command-line terminal in this folder, and run:

   - `npm install keythereum`
   - `node run.js`

---

**Contents of `run.js`:**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const keythereum = require("keythereum");

const KEYSTORE = "KeystoreFileName";
const PASSWORD = "YourPassword";

const keyObject = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(KEYSTORE, {encoding: "utf8"}));
const privateKey = keythereum.recover(PASSWORD, keyObject).toString("hex");
console.log(`0x${keyObject.address}: 0x${privateKey}`);
```

In the code above, replace:

- The string `"KeystoreFileName"` with the key-store file name
- The string `"YourPassword"` with your password

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Only(and big) issue is that I also do not know my password anymore so that is why I am trying to find a way to access my wallet with only the keystore file.

Comment: @Swinks95: If you have any vague idea about your password, then you can try several options using the script above, until `"0x" + keyObject.address === YourWalletAddress`.

Comment: In which environment do I have to do all this? I normally work with python in juptyer but I am not familiair with NodeJS

Comment: @Swinks95: The above code is in NodeJS, as explicitly stated in the answer. But assuming that you do have a few combinations in mind that you can iterate on, it shouldn't be much of a problem in Javascript.

Comment: thanks for sharing your inputs here. Sorry for reaching you out of the blue. I was wondering if you could assist me with this. I am kind of not finding any information anywhere else.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118130/swap-for-tokens-with-bot-protection-enabled-bpenabled
Thanks a ton in advance.