# Swap for tokens with Bot Protection Enabled (BpEnabled)

Tags: solidity, web3js, etherscan, pancakeswap, bscscan

!!Apology in advance for such verbosity!!

**Background**

> I came across this BEP20 token (0xcc7a91413769891de2e9ebbfc96d2eb1874b5760) which had sufficient Liquidity added at TGE but bot protection was enabled. The rules were the swap to be allowed only on or after a certain time (say at 7:00 AM) with only whitelisted wallet addresses to be able to buy up to 2500 (worth $200 say) tokens for the first 180s and then it gets opened to all.

> When the Liquidity got added (say at 6:50 AM), I could see the conversion rate on PancakeSwap but every time I click the Swap button, it was showing me the `Transfer Failed` error and not even submitting the transaction on the blockchain. Once the go-ahead was given by the project team that token is live for swap, if I (Note: I was a WL address) set the amount greater than $200, PancakeSwap was still giving `Transfer Failed` error and not submitting the transaction. This was not the slippage issue, as I tried setting it to the highest and still didn't make the difference.

[image]

**Question**

- Apart from Liquidity Pair & sufficient liquidity amount check, what else PancakeSwap (Router Contract) checks before submitting the swap transaction?
- How PancakeSwap determined though the Liquidity Exists the token is not yet swappable?
- How PancakeSwap did determine the limit on buy amount?
- Not sure if PancakeSwap also has the ability to know if the wallet address is the Whitelisted one before submitting the transaction?

[image: BSC Scan Token Swap]

If you see in the image there is a roughly 10 mins difference between the AddLiquidity transaction and the first swap. I checked the first swap address and that person had submitted multiple transactions before (which I guess either through sniper bot or maybe through Write contract option of PancakeRouter BscScan) and of course, all failed until the time & amount criteria were met. And all the failed transactions had the same `Transfer Failed` error too.

> (Success txn: 0xb1e0e23c34e0a8090d4ef879792701eb324ef83c1d95f5eee5cf95bb89ad24bb, wallet: 0x96d5f755220a03712eb85d490659288f859ccb8e, Failed Txn: 0xe80ff57297df7f580c726e923d200da6357c3ddac4b50f279b9504012054b32e)

So how one can determine the swap-ability of such token through web3j code libraries without submitting the transaction (meant to fail)? And which contract to interact with?

> NOTE: I did notice the BP contract 0xb930a172f9205f87f7d28ffa6cc3b5c3fd87ac19 doesn't have code available to understand it better. Bytecode decompilers are not of much help. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I traced a transaction to find the root of the error.

The `Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED` is thrown by the pancakeswap pair when it is unable to transfer a token.

The reason given for the transfer fail is `BP: the address is not whitelisted`. The BP contract has not been verified on bscscan so I am not sure what caused the error, but based on the description it is simply because your address was not whitelisted.

As for your other questions: Pancakeswap simply tries the transaction virtually and see that it fails, then gives you the error on the UI. You can do the same with web3js by making a [call](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.0-rc.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) on the function that you want to try. Depending on the type of swap that you want to do, the pancakeswap router has different functions that you can use.

Comment: Thanks for promptly responding. This definitely helps. But how were you able to trace the exact root cause `BP: the address is not whitelisted`? I don't see that information anywhere in the TransactionReceipt or BscScan.

Comment: There are many ways, but in this case I used tenderly.co app