# Is it necessary to convert a file into a "Buffer or Readable stream" before adding it to IPFS?

Tags: javascript, ipfs

I've uploaded some files using *js-ipfs* without converting it into Buffer or Readable stream, and it works just fine.

since IPFS converts the file into blocks anyway, why use buffer/stream!

what are the pros and cons of this?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the service you use to upload the files. They may have different requirements, but the end result is the same.

Using buffers/streams is mostly useful if you're dealing with lots of data and/or in an environment where memory is limited. Streaming data means you don't transfer all at once, but send smaller pieces all the time. That wait the recipient doesn't need to accept a big file at once, which may drain resources.

Comment: am using js-ipfs

Comment: thanks for sharing your inputs here. Sorry for reaching you out of the blue. I was wondering if you could assist me with this. I am kind of not finding any information anywhere else.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118130/swap-for-tokens-with-bot-protection-enabled-bpenabled
Thanks a ton in advance.